# Error while registering Public key in Openshift

Tags: ruby, git, openshift

I'm getting an error while add my public key & it showing this error code: "
*`Error updating settings on gear: 01779aa6c3e04c71be82fbaa10662fcf with status: -1 and output:`* "

Any idea that why this is showing everytime when I am registering public key.....//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same error. Looks like its their internal server problem..

EDIT: it seems you can't put security on applications that are available for test in openShift. It makes sense. Remove the test applications that you got from OpenShift.

I got it solved. That number {01779aa6c3e04c71be82fbaa10662fcf} is an application you currently have in your domain. I removed all applications in there. Have backups first, then clean your domain. Update your public key again and I am 100% sure it will work.

Please do this with care. Back up your application first. To remove

```
rhc app destroy -a {appName} -d
```

Comment: At the time of ssh,I'm getting an error "No supported authentication methods available(server sent:public key,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)" - any idea why I'm getting this error while log into my application.

Comment: Hey bobby,recently I'm getting an (perhaps to say an absurd)error,I have posted the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562520/getting-error-in-openshift-while-pushing-my-app ,could you take a look and any kind of inputs from yourside will be more than a warm welcome !! :)

Answer (score 3):

We believe this is a problem that arose in our most recent update on tuesday and are now investigating.  When you add an SSH key we copy it to each of your applications (so git will work) - it looks like the copy process started failing.

EDIT: We fixed an issue in production that was affecting a small number of users that resulted in this symptom.  Please let us know if the issue is not fixed, and we'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

***It's was my silly mistake, just I have to add my private key at the time of authentication in Putty.***