# Getting error in Openshift while pushing my app

Tags: java, git, openshift

I'm getting some error while pushing my app (already built a Java EE application using Tomcat 6.) in OpenShift.

***server**: JBoss Application Server 7.1
**database**: MySQL Database 5.1*

*Here is src folder structure of Openshift*

```
com
--simsystech
--Add.java (using apache log4j api || import org.apache.log4j.Logger)
--Edit.java (using csv reader api || import org.apache.log4j.Logger & import org.apache.log4j.Logger)
--Import.java (using csv reader api || import org.apache.log4j.Logger & import org.apache.log4j.Logger)
--Create.java
--Delete.java
```

*webapp folder structure is* :

```
webapp
--css
--image
--images1
--jscript
--jsp(all my jsp pages are here)
--META-INF
--WEB-INF
--classes
--lib(JAR files are here:opencsv-2.3,log4j-1.2.9,javacsv)
```

My application name:simsystech,and whenever I'm writing cmd prompt-> git push , I'm getting error like :

```
a>remote: /var/lib/stickshift/38fe42fe1d8f469c90f496990182c478/app-root/runtime/re
po/src/main/java/com/simsystech/Delete.java:[3,23] error: package org.apache.lo
g4j does not exist


b>remote: /var/lib/stickshift/38fe42fe1d8f469c90f496990182c478/app-root/runtime/re
po/src/main/java/com/simsystech/Import.java:[92,2] error: cannot find symbol
remote: [ERROR] class Import

c>remote: [ERROR] class Export
remote: /var/lib/stickshift/38fe42fe1d8f469c90f496990182c478/app-root/runtime/re
po/src/main/java/com/simsystech/Edit.java:[20,20] error: cannot find symbol
```

Error like: "package org.apache.lo
g4j does not exist" is very strange !! :(

Where I'm going wrong while deploying it in openshift..?
Any inputs on this regards will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we use Maven to build your project you need to make sure those dependencies are referenced properly in your Maven pom.xml. What does pom.xml look like?

Comment: could we tell this thing in details ...?